# Condition for closed orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, oscillators

I'd like to know when an orbit is closed. I know that, to have a closed orbit, there is a ratio that must be a rational number, but I don't know other things..

Comment: what closed orbit are you taking about. Give us the detailed information about what do you want to know

Comment: @Akash There isn't a general rule to apply for any case? For example.... we can consider a mass point on a cone: what is the condition to have closed orbit? thanks!

Comment: @sunrise Isn't it just a case of having the eccentricity less than 1? If $e=0$, the orbit is a circle, if $0 < e < 1$, the orbit is an ellipse, if $e=1$, the orbit is a parabola, is $e>1$, the orbit is a hyperbola. Only for the circle and ellipse are the orbits closed.

Answer (score 3):

There's a branch of study called [dynamical systems theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_systems_theory) that deals with questions like this.  The answer is not straightforward, except in a handful of cases.  Trajectories can appear to be highly chaotic and yet, when observed for a sufficiently long time, will turn out to be perfectly periodic.  The notion of [Poincairé recurrence time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem) arises, which suggests that over a long enough time, any orbit must be considered periodic.  This, in turn, leads to a debate over whether there is such a thing as an irrational number in a physical system with lower limits to measurable lengths and times.

The straightforward answer to this very broad question is that there isn't a straightforward answer.

Comment: Your answer is very very interesting! :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to KDN's nice answer, there is a theorem called [Bertrand's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) which states that in the case of a particle moving in a central potential, the only potentials that produce stable, closed orbits are the inverse square and radial harmonic oscillator potentials.

Comment: Thank you! mmmmh.. any idea to theorems about ratios?

Comment: @sunrise No, not offhand.

Comment: I believe that there are also circular orbits in a $r^{-5}$ potential, but they go through the center of force where things are singular. It does not contradict Bertrand's theorem because it is not a general result for that power law. See Goldstein (Ed. 2) problem 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to rational ratios suggests that you might be thinking of the 
simple dynamical system on the torus---a favourite toy example of mathematicians.
See, for example, the wikipedia article "Linear flow on the torus".

Comment: I'm thinking to a quiet simple system, but I don't know the torus.. other analogous cases that can be answer to my question?